# Replace comma with a dot while typing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Hi i want to replace a comma with a dot while typing in a text input field using jQuery. I have this code right now;

```
$(document).on('change', '.unitprice', function() {
  $(this).val().replace(/,/g, '.');
});
```

> The class of the input field is **unitprice**

But it's not working.. And i can't seem to find the correct answer on google. Anybody has an idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're just changing the variable and not writing it back.

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
```

Comment: Upvoted because you're right, but I'd suggest: `$(this).val(function(index, currentValue) { return currentValue.replace(/,/g, '.'); });` rather than using `$(this).val()` twice (unnecessarily). Or, for brevity: `this.value = this.value.replace(...);`

Comment: Didn't know about it. It always felt off to write it this way, but I never came across this. Thanks for the info.

Comment: this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '.'); is useful aswell thanks David.